# Conversion of PHP to C#

Tags: c#, php, sockets, minecraft, data-conversion

I've been working on this for about an hour now and I can't manage to get the uint16 packed in the right format in C#.

PHP:

```
$data = "\x00"; //packet id
$data .= "\x04"; //protocol version
$data .= pack('c', strlen($server_address)) . $server_address; //server address
$data .= pack('n', $server_port); //server port
$data .= "\x01"; //next state

$data = pack('c', strlen($data)) . $data;

return $data;
```

C#:

```
string packet_id = "\x00";
string protocol_version = "\x04";
string server_address = new string(new char[] { Convert.ToChar(this.server_address.Length) }) + this.server_address;
//byte[] port_array = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)this.server_port);
//Array.Reverse(port_array);
string server_port = Convert.ToString((ushort)this.server_port);
string next_state = "\x01";

string final = packet_id + protocol_version + server_address + server_port + next_state;
final = new string(new char[] { Convert.ToChar(final.Length) }) + final;
```

The results as hex are as follows:
PHP:

```
12 00 04 0C 31 39 38 2E 32 37 2E 38 33 2E 33 35 63 DE 01
```

C#:

```
15 00 04 0C 31 39 38 2E 32 37 2E 38 33 2E 33 35 32 35 35 36 36 01
```

As you can see the server port (25566) is 63 DE in PHP but 32 35 35 36 36 in C#.

Comment: Doesnt "\x01" escape the x value? Shouldnt it be @"\x01" ? (same with the rest of the strings that have x)

Comment: C# writes server port as a string, it should writes it as a number

Comment: This is a string that I'm going to send to a socket, the server is very picky on formatting so it has to be exact and I can't manage to emulate php's pack("n", ".."); function properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is with a byte array and bitwise operations:

```
byte[] data = new byte[] {
    (byte) (((ushort) this.server_port) >> 8),
    (byte) ((ushort) this.server_port)
};
string server_port = (string) data;
```

It's also worth noting that your PHP output actually depicts `25565`, *not* `25566`. As you can see [here](http://ideone.com/VcCxb5), `25566` is actually `63DE` in hex.

Comment: I don't think you can typecast a byte array as a string.

Comment: So technically I'm emulating php's pack("n", ..) function with C# which means uint16 in the big endian format.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this code for conversion of port:

```
this.server_port.ToString("X")
```

It will convert number you gave to hexadecimal representation in string

Comment: That would work make the correct output but it would make it 63DE as a text and not hex.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to ping a server? I suggest using [Craft.Net](https://github.com/SirCmpwn/Craft.Net), instead of trying to roll your own.

Comment: That doesn't help me learn sockets in the slightest, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: You never said you were trying to learn sockets. This answer solves your problem.